# Secondary dropdown field not operational

Tags: html, forms, dropdown

The second dropdown field of my form will not populate and I am not sure why it will not work. I have my html linking to the jquery repository, and I do believe my JS works because it is operational in my fiddle when the other form fields are deleted. I am just not aware of what to do to fix this issue.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>
<form class="reg-page" method="post" action="http://www.aviationmaintenance.edu/php/sendinfo.php" data-ajax="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="first_Name" placeholder="First Name" required><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="last_Name" placeholder="Last Name" required><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required>
            <br><br>
            <select class="form-control" id="campus" name="campus" required="" 
    title="Campus">
    <option value="AIMNAT" style="alignment-adjust:middle;" 
 selected="selected">Select Your Nearest Location</option>
    <option value="AMA">Atlanta, GA</option>
    <option value="AMD">Dallas, TX</option>
    <option value="AMH">Houston, TX</option>
    <option value="AMK">Kansas City, MO</option>
    <option value="AIML">Las Vegas, NV</option>
    <option value="AMP">Philadelphia, PA</option>
    <option value="AMS">San Francisco, CA</option>
    <option value="AMN">Virginia Beach, VA</option>
    <option value="AMM">Washington, DC</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
<select id='dates'>
<option selected="selected">Select Your Schedule</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type = "hidden" name = "LinkId" value ="d5a1336b-f6a0-434a-b3c9-d5e174963c67" /> <input type = "submit" value = "Purchase Your Course" /> 
</form>
```

JS

```
var locations = {
AMA : { 
  0: "Select Your Schedule",
  1: "August 19-20",
  2: "September 19-20",
  3: "January 19-20",
  },
AMD : { 
  0: "Select Your Schedule",
  1: "August 5-6",
  2: "August 12-13",
  3: "September 9-10",
  4: "September 16-17",
  5: "October 14-15",
  6: "October 21-22",
  7: "November 11-12",
  8: "November 18-19",
  },
AMH : {
  0: "Select Your Schedule",
  1: "August 5-6",
  2: "August 12-13",
  3: "September 23-24",
  4: "September 30-1",
  },
AMK : { 
  0: "Select Your Schedule",
  1: "August 26-27",
  },
AIML : {
  0: "August 19-22",
  1: "October 21-22",
 },
AMS : { 
  0: "Select Your Schedule",
  1: "September 23 & 30",
  },
AMP : { 
  0: "Select Your Schedule",
  1: "August 26-27",
  },
AMN : { 
  0: "Select Your Schedule",
  1: "September 16-17",
  2: "September 23-24",
  },
AMM : { 
  0: "Select Your Schedule",
  1: "October 14-15",
  2: "October 21-22",
  },
  };

// when user selects a location
$('#campus').on('change', function() {
// get selected option
var location = $('#campus').find(':selected').val();
// clear the pervious options for dates
$('#dates').empty();

// popluate dates
$.each(locations[location], function(index) {
  $('#dates').append('<option value="' + index + '">' + this + "</option>");
 });
 });
```

You may also see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/inetmgraim/meg59861/)

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: It works fine when you update your jquery reference.
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't change anything for me :(

Comment: Is this what you'd expect to see? http://i.imgur.com/m390qPL.png

Comment: Why yes, it is!

Comment: Yeah, all I did was replace your jquery link, as it seems to have some kind of weird symbol in it on jsfiddle: http://i.imgur.com/9bRs8tE.png

Comment: Hmm, odd, because even when I replace my link with the one you provided it still has that red 'dash' symbol.

Comment: I just deleted the 'dash' and replaced it with an 'e' because it deleted it for some reason. It runs great!! Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome, weird bug is weird! Ill leave an answer to help future visitors, though this seems like a very specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, your jsfiddle shows that you have a weird symbol in the reference to your Jquery library.

[image]

Simply removing the symbol or replacing it with the proper jquery reference should fix the issue:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```